# KafkaStreams metrics, records processed per stream/extracting offset for each stream in topology

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using `org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams` and for example my topology looks this:

```
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    builder.stream("input-topic1")
            .mapValues((readOnlyKey, value) -> value.toUpperCase())
            .to("output-topic1");

    builder.stream("input-topic2")
            .mapValues((readOnlyKey, value) -> value.toUpperCase())
            .to("output-topic2");
```

Every two minutes by default KafkaStream logs:

`Processed 14 total records, ran 0 punctuators, and committed 11 total tasks since the last update"}`

I would like to have better overview if I have any incoming messages into each input topic. I want to see some more metrics out of each stream instead of total number records processed. Is it possible to give a name for a stream and then extract for example offset for `builder.stream("input-topic1")` and `builder.stream("input-topic2")` seperately? Or to have possibility to know how many records each stream processed in some kind of time frame.

- Maybe i could use `.peek` and have some kind of static variable out of the stream, but i consider such approach very bad practice.
- I also looked into KafkaStreams metrics, but i havent found such functionality im looking for.
- Logging each time my streams processes one message is not an option too, because it would generate too many logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> better overview if I have any incoming messages into each input topic

This is simply consumer lag metric, which can be monitored, yes

Related post just asked - [exposing kafka topic LAGs using kafka jmx exporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77401829/exposing-kafka-topic-lags-using-kafka-jmx-exporter)

> Maybe i could use .peek and have some kind of static variable out of the stream

You could use a Micrometer metric registry. That's not a bad practice at all

Comment: Is it possible to extract lag metric per topic through KafkaStreams.metrics()?

Comment: I haven't used Kafka Streams in a few years, but I think it's included there. It's a JMX metric, anyway, so people often use Prometheus JMX Exporter, Datadog agent, etc to get the value, not with metrics in the code