# exposing kafka topic LAGs using kafka jmx exporter

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, jmx, jmx-exporter

I am trying to expose the Prometheus metric that shows LAG value in each Kafka topic. I use [kafka_exporter](https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter) for exporting Kafka metrics.

I added this pattern in `prom-jmx-agent.config.yaml`

```
lowercaseOutputName: true
rules:
- pattern: kafka.consumer<type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics, client-id=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.+)><>(records-lag)
  name: kafka_consumer_fetch_records_lag
  labels:
    clientId: "$1"
    topic: "$2"
    partition: "$3"
    help: "Kafka Consumer Fetch Records Lag"
    type: GAUGE
```

I create some lags to be able to see in the Prometheus

[Describe consumer group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwP2r.png)

I expect to see metric named  `kafka_consumer_fetch_records_lag` but it does not appear in the metric list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above JMX exporter config must be added to JVM-based consumer clients. The brokers don't have `kafka_consumer_fetch_records_lag` metric

If you want to find lag of all clients (including non JVM ones),

- https://github.com/seglo/kafka-lag-exporter
- https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow
- https://github.com/zalando-incubator/remora

Comment: Thank you for showing me the right direction. Just for an update, kafka-lag-exporter doesn't show lags, when there is no active consumer in the consumer group and consumer group consuming more than one topic. https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter was a better solution.